# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'srcObject')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

We are currently working on a video calling web system, and the problem is that the user can't see himself, but when they call, they can see who they are calling. But they cannot see his own video.

Additional Question: Is there a possibility of creating a permanent ID, like Google Meet Code, that works even after refreshing the page?

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import Peer from 'simple-peer'

const SocketContext = createContext();

// const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
// const socket = io('https://socketproject.bjmpbaliwag.xyz');
const socket = io('https://bjmp-socket-server.herokuapp.com');

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
    const [me, setMe] = useState('');
    const [call, setCall] = useState({});
    const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
    const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const myVideo = useRef();
    const userVideo = useRef();
    const connectionRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUserMedia = async () => {
            try {
                const currentStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})
                setStream(currentStream)
                myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        getUserMedia();
        // navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})
        // .then((currentStream) => {
        //     setStream(currentStream);

        //     myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        // });

        socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

        socket.on('calluser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
            setCall({ isReceivedCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal })
        });
    }, []);

    const answerCall = () => {
        setCallAccepted(true)

        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

        peer.on('signal', (data) => {
            socket.emit('answercall', { signal: data, to: call.from });
        });

        peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });

        peer.signal(call.signal);

        connectionRef.current = peer;
    }

    const callUser = (id) => {
        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

        peer.on('signal', (data) => {
            socket.emit('calluser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
        });

        peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });

        socket.on('callaccepted', (signal) => {
            setCallAccepted(true);

            peer.signal(signal);
        });

        connectionRef.current = peer;
    }

    const leaveCall = () => {
        setCallEnded(true);

        connectionRef.current.destroy();

        window.location.reload();
    }

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{ call, callAccepted, myVideo, userVideo, stream, name, setName, callEnded, me, callUser, leaveCall, answerCall, }}>
            {children}

        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you find this type of Error,
So You can use

```
    if (myVideo.current) 
    {
        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    }
```

in place of **userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;**
this function is called in **useEffect** field.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace this... `userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;`  to this `userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream.streams[0];`

I Think it should works...